# Building a conditional statement for a calculated field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a subform inside with logistic purchase information in several fields. So one field is called PURCHASEid (with the purchase number), another combobox field is called PICKINGCODE and its values can be A, B or C. Then I have another fields called BOXES SUM and PALLETS NUMBER I would like It to work as follows:

- When PICKINGCODE field value is A, PALLETS NUMBER value can be filled by typing a number.
- When PICKINGCODE field value is B or C:
  o   PALLETS NUMBER value will be the 1/count of fields that have B value in PICKINGCODE field.

For example for PURCHASEid “4” and 2 records with “B” PICKINGCODE value, I would like to have “0,5” PALLETNUMBER value for both records
In the subform event Afterupdate I wrote:

```
    If Me. PICKINGCODE.Value = "A" Then
         Me. [PALLET NUMBER].Value = "*"
       Else Me. [PALLETS NUMBER].Value = 1 / acAggregateCount([&PICKINGCODE])
```

But I know at least the last statement It’s wrong. Could you please help me to build it? I wrote acAggregateCount([&PALETPICKINGCOD]) to count records in a given purchase with the same PALETPICKINGCOD value of the record selected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you know it's wrong - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? acAggregateCount is a VBA custom function? Saving aggregate calc data is usually unnecessary and bad design. Calculate when needed. If you want to modify multiple records, use an UPDATE action SQL.

Comment: Thanks, June7, but unfortunately I have no knowledge about SQL so, It`s difficult to me trying to build an UPDATE action SQL. Could you please guide me a little bit to build an example like this? I'd be so grateful.